# Intellij and sbt: How to make intellij to read custom configuration file for my play application tests?

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, sbt, playframework-2.0

For my test (Play Framework 2.6 app) I want to use different configuration file.

For this, I've added the following line into `build.sbt`

`javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf"`

When I run tests from sbt (`sbt test`), it works fine, reads the custom configuration file.

But when running tests from IntelliJ IDEA, it ignores this setting and uses `application.conf` file.

How to force IntelliJ to use this sbt setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to edit your intellij configurations. 
To do that use this : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html.

Once you're in the edit configurations page, add ScalaTest into the list of your configurations. Then add `-Dconfig.file=conf/application.test.conf` under VM Parameters.

Save, and done!

Comment: Hello @Teimuraz did you get it?

Comment: Doesn't work with me. Intellij always creates a new config for the test run instead of using my previously created one (with -Dconfig.file in VM paras).